# Differentiate between expired session and new user in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using the standard Authentication middleware in my `Startup.cs` file like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("auth")
    .AddCookie("auth", options => 
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/index");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/forbidden");
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

I want to be able to display a "Your session has expired" message on my login page once the user is redirected there because of an expired session. And obviously not have it there when a new user is visiting the page.

By the looks of it, the Authentication middleware simply checks for a 401 passed from another middleware and changes it to a 302 to my desired location, leaving me no chance of differentiating between those two.

Can I achieve this differentiation by using the standard .net core 2.0 libraries, or should I go for a custom implementation instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to detect whether or not the user was logged in, you could set a second unrelated Session cookie saying that the user HAD a session. Do not store any other information in the cookie. Let's call this a 'Flag' cookie.

When the user logs in, you create both a session cookie and a flag cookie. The session cookie can expire whenever you set it to, and the flag cookie should never expire. Lets say after 30 days, you are automatically logged out of your account - the session cookie should expire. Because you still have the flag cookie but not the session cookie, you can check on each page if you have the flag cookie when no session cookie is present.

If the Flag cookie exists but the actual session cookie does not, you can redirect to the login page and inform them that their login session has expired. I'd be sure to delete the cookie once you get there too so that every time they load a page they aren't redirected to login. This means the message will only show once to the user so they can still try visiting other pages on the site afterwards without being redirected should they want to browse (for example the homepage) but not want to log back in. If they attempt to access an authenticated page, they should be prompted for credentials again